# Count how many times numbers from one array occur in another

Tags: php

I'm sure this is simple and I'm just failing at phrasing it correctly for google. Hopefully I can spell it out well enough here that someone can point me in the right direction!

I'm using php and chart.js to chart stats about mma fighters and I want to chart how many wins (or losses or ko's, etc. etc. they had **per year**.

I've been able to create an array that shows the year of each loss (note that there are repeats in there went multiple losses occurred in a year)

e.g.

```
$loss_years = Array ( [0] => 2019 [1] => 2016 [2] => 2014 [3] => 2013 [4] => 2012 [5] => 2011 [6] => `2011 [7] => 2010 [8] => 2009 [9] => 2009 [10] => 2006 [11] => 2005 )`
```

I've been able to count how many losses occur in each of the years that losses do occur like so:

```
array_count_values(array_reverse ($loss_years)));
```

Which outputs:

```
array(10) { ["2005 "]=> int(1) ["2006 "]=> int(1) ["2009 "]=> int(2) ["2010 "]=> int(1) ["2011 "]=> int(2) ["2012 "]=> int(1) ["2013 "]=> int(1) ["2014 "]=> int(1) ["2016 "]=> int(1) ["2019 "]=> int(1) }
```

However I want to be able to cross-reference it with every year of their career.

So if their career span is represented as:

```
$career_span = Array ( [0] => 2004 [1] => 2005 [2] => 2006 [3] => 2007 [4] => 2008 [5] => 2009 [6] => 2010 [7] => 2011 [8] => 2012 [9] => 2013 [10] => 2014 [11] => 2015 [12] => 2016 [13] => 2017 [14] => 2018 [15] => 2019 [16] => 2020 )
```

Then I want to cross-reference that with $loss_years and output a third array $losses_per_year that'd look something like :

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 2 [6] => 1 [7] => 2 [8] => 1 [9] => 1 [10] => 1 [11] => 0 [12] => 1 [13] => 0 [14] => 0 [15] => 1 [16] => 0 )
```

Does that make sense?

Is there some much simpler way to go about it that I'm not finding?

Comment: You'll just need to iterate through the array using a `for each` loop, increasing the counter each time the value equals the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the `$career_span` array with a `foreach` loop and check the number of losses for each career year in the `$loss_years` array (after applying `array_count_values` to it).

You can use the [PHP ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to check if the there is an array key in `$loss_years` that matches the career year. If so, add the number of losses for that year. If not, add zero.

```
$loss_years = array_count_values( $loss_years );
foreach ( $career_span as $career_year ) {
    $losses_per_year[] = array_key_exists( $career_year, $loss_years ) ? $loss_years[$career_year] : 0;
}
```

Comment: No problem. If you could upvote you'd make my weekend. ;)

Comment: Done! Didn't actually realize upvoting was a thing here haha

Comment: Great! Thank you. :)